# How to let Timestamp object show in type long in JSON?

Tags: java, json

I've a Java class **User** in my project and it has 2 attributes `id` and `created`.

**User.java**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private Timestamp created;

    public User (int id) {
        this.id = id;
        created = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    // getters and setters...
}
```

Now I need to generate a JSON object representing an instance of `User`. So I use the **org.json.JSONObject** to do it :

```
User user = new User(1);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(user);
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Here's the result.

```
{"id":1,"created":"2016-03-02 19:08:00.0"}
```

However, I want a format in Long, which is like

```
{"id":1,"created":1456945720000}
```

I think I might be able to change it by modifying the property in JSONObject, but I want to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.getTime()` to convert in to long.
If you are getting an object in variable "created" then convert it into long :

```
created.getTime();
```

Comment: That's what I'm thinking about. But in this way, I need to create the JSON object, then put / overwrite the value for `created` key in long. Am I right ?

Comment: yes you need to overwrite. and what you will get if you write `json.created` ?

Comment: You can't do `json.created`. java is not like python ^^ JSONObject do not have attribute `created`